# Find all group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Find all group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $S_5$.

I think to use the first theorem of homomprphism. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic, the image of homomorphism is a cyclic subgroup of $S_5$. The orders of elements in $S_5$ are $1,2,3,4,5,6$, and I have to find how many each of them are. They are $1,25,20,30,24,20$, respectively. Let us map $1$ to $x$ where $x$ is any element of $S_5$ of order $3$. Then I think in this way I will get $10$ homomorphisms. Same with other order elements. Is it correct?

Comment: There are several homomorphism that have the same subgroup as their image (unless the image has order $\leqslant 2$, in which case the image determines the homomorphism).

Comment: A map $\mathbb{Z} \to X$ for a group $X$ is just a choice of element $x\in X$; the corresponding map is given by $1 \to x$. (This is effectively the definition of a free group.)

Comment: See an answer [here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_algebraist_2006&task=show_msg&msg=1343.0001), question 2).

Comment: Every homomorphism $h: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow S_5$ is uniquely determined by its image $h(1)$, so there are $5!$ different homomorphisms. If you consider two homomorphisms as equivalent if $h'(1) = g^{-1}h(1)g$ for some g, then you have only one homomorphism per conjugacy class of $S_5$, In this case you have only $7$ homomorphisms.